# jquery .each and rails

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to translate this script to jQuery. See rails casts [#88](http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus)

```
var colors = new Array();
<%= for color in @colors %>
  colors.push(new Array(<%= colot.product_id %>, '<%= color.name %>', <%= color.id %>));
<% end %>

function productSelected() {
  product_id = $('order_items_attributes_0_product_id').val();
  options = $('item_color_id').options;
  colors.each(function(color) {
    if (color[0] == product_id) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(color[1], color[2]);
    }
  });
  if (options.length == 1) {
    $('color_field').hide();
  } else {
    $('color_field').show();
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  productSelected();
  $('order_items_attributes_0_product_id').change(productSelected);
});
```

Firebug says

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'colors.each(function(color) {
    if (color[0] == product_id) {
      options[options.length] = new Option(color[1], color[2]);
    }
  })')
```

Also the ruby code is no longer allowed in 3.1.1 js files (under assets)? It also complains about `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of `.each` is wrong. Use:

```
$.each(colors, function(){
```

`colors` is an array, which does not have the JQuery `.each` method. The `$.each` function accepts to parameters:

1. Element to loop through
2. Function to run at each loop

#### See also

- http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thanks. Now complains about TypError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'options.length = 1')

Comment: You have to use `$('item_color_id').get(0).options;`, because you're trying to access a DOM property. `$(..).get(0)` returns the first DOM element which match the JQuery selector.

Comment: `options = $('item_color_id').options;
  $('item_color_id').get(0).options;` results to `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$('item_color_id').get(0).options')`

Comment: If `item_color_id` is an ID, add a sharp before it: `#item_color_id`. You have to add a sharp `#` to your other selectors as well.

Comment: Thx again. Making progress but now have `TypError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'options.length')`

Comment: Show your *generated* JavaScript source.